# Where can I download wallpapers from the changing "Community Wallpaper for Ubunu 12.04"

Tags: desktop-background

I currently have my wallpaper set to the community wallpaper for Ubuntu 12.04 that changes throughout the day. I really like the current image that's on there. Is there somewhere that I can go to download the wallpaper to save for later?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

they are already in your PC ;) Check in `/usr/share/backgrounds`

Answer (score 0):

They should all be located in `/usr/share/wallpapers`. You can investigate the folder and search for whichever wallpaper you desire, and then copy it to somewhere in your home folder for later. Or, you can remember where the file is located and set it as the wallpaper image file.

Comment: No such folder in 15.04